# Run a command before services are started

Tags: rhel, startup, services

I have a Oracle Linux 6.3 system on which I would like to run a command when the machines starts up *before* any other services are started. The reason for this is to try and work around [a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=783884) in RHEL 6.

I know that `rc.local` exists, but that is run after all other services have been run and is therefore too late.

Here is the order in which things are currently run:

- Oracle 11g (fails due to RHEL bug)
- One or more things that depend on Oracle (fail due to no Oracle)
- `rc.local` (too late to help)

Ideally I would like to do it this way:

- Command which works around bug.
- Oracle
- One or more things that depend on Oracle.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Here are some options I have thought of so far that I would like to avoid as they add complexity and/or are just a bit nasty:

- Creating a custom service that is run before everything else.
- Adding the command to `rc.local` followed by calls to `service <x> start` for all the things that didn't start up.

Comment: In what way it adds unnecessary complexity? It's the shortest path to what you want to do.

Comment: It's a single command I want to run (a remount). Adding a service seems pointless overhead. Some background that I didn't add is that what I'm creating is an image for a system that will be deployed in multiple locations and managed by people who aren't me.

Comment: @schaiba Also, *is it* the shortest path? That's part of what I'm trying to work out here.

Comment: I'd hack it into Oracle's startup script, as a last resort. Check the script doing the original mount, maybe that one (or /etc/fstab, or the automount configuration) is broken. Check if the problem really is that Oracle is being started too early (perhaps this is fixed in another script that either isn't run or runs too late). In any case, RHEL + Oracle is one of the premier combinations, I'd be surprised if nobody else has tripped over this (unless your setup is rather bizarre).

Comment: I ended up just doing `mount -o remount /dev/shm` in the Oracle startup script (with a comment point to the bugzilla entry) as I didn't find a better option. Thanks for the suggestion @vonbrand